# HQL query to find the data using in clause

Tags: java, hql

I am trying to access the certain data using **in clause** but the following 
exception

> unexpected token: Customer near line 1, column 81 [from 
>   app.com.db.DTO.SmsSourceDTO as sms where sms.description  in  (
>   Registered Customer,External DB,Birthday)]

displayed

SmsSourceDTO.java

```
   @Table(name = "sms_source_tbl")
    public class SmsSourceDTO implements Serializable {

        private Integer id;
        private String description;
   }
```

.

TestHql.java

```
       listOfSelectedDatabase  = {Registered Customer,External DB,Birthday};

      String hqlString = "from SmsSourceDTO as sms where sms.description in(" + listOfSelectedDatabase  +")";
        getResultSetByHQL(hqlString));

       protected List getResultSetByHQL(String hql) throws DataBaseException {
            Query query = null;

            query = getHbSession().createQuery(hql);
            session = null;
            return query.list();
       }
```

while debugging I got the following query => `from SmsSourceDTO as sms where sms.description  in  ( Registered Customer,External DB,Birthday)`

Can anybody help.

Comment: Post compilable code. Use parameters in your query, rather than concatenation: `from SmsSourceDTO as sms where sms.description in :list`. And please don't name your entities `DTO`. A DTO is a data transfer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a parameter list to an HQL query. I recommend you to use hibernate parameter binding to do this.

So first, if you want to include a list of string values, creates it before using

```
List<String> listOfSelectedDatabase = Arrays.asList("Registered Customer", "External DB", "Birthday");
```

instead

```
listOfSelectedDatabase = {Registered Customer,External DB,Birthday};
```

Then creates a param in HQL query and provide its value as follows:

```
String hqlString = "from SmsSourceDTO as sms where sms.description in (:paramList)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hqlString);
query.setParameterList("paramList", listOfSelectedDatabase);
```

Finally, what is this `session = null;` for? I don't get the point of that sentence.